# doing something to `__getattr__` of a class, resulting in weird bug: any commands in python console calls what's in `__getattr__` twice

Tags: python, class, oop, getattr

For example, here is a module:

```
class Foo:

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        print('haha')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    foo = Foo()
```

Now I run this module with python console. It gives

```
haha
haha
```

why "haha" twice?

Now I just randomly type `3` in the console:

```
In[2]: 3
Output[2]: 3
haha
haha
```

what's going on?

Edit: I am using pycharm (which uses ipython?). After I added `print(item)` to `__getattr__`, now the output has another line: `__len__` after each `haha`:

```
In[3]: 4
Output[3]: 4
haha
__len__
haha
__len__
```

Comment: Try adding `print(item)` to the definition of `Foo.__getattr__` to see which attribute is being accessed by your REPL.

Comment: I guess your REPL (ipython? jupyter?) is doing some funny introspection stuff, otherwise `haha` should not be printed at all (assuming that this is the code that *actually* runs)

Comment: I am using pycharm (which uses ipython?). After I added `print(item)`, now the output has another line: `__len__` after each `haha`.

Comment: This is more confusing now, where is `__len__` from?

Comment: What do you expect, then? Isn't that what `__getattr__` should do?

Comment: @user202729 completely confused, why does the `__getattr__` have anything to do with `__len__`? The example module in the question is the script that actually runs.

Comment: `__len__` is the method that gets called by the `len` builtin function (to get the length). I guess pycharm is either checking to see if `foo` has a `__len__` attribute, or it's trying to get the length of `foo` and it's ignoring the exception from calling `None()`. Maybe it wants to know if `foo` matches the [Sized](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Sized) interface?

Comment: @luther Is there a way to tell/see behind the scenes what pycharm python console is secretly doing?